# HTML5 video scaling algorithm

Tags: html, video, html5-video

I am displaying a video content in a bigger HTML5 video element (preserving aspect ratio). I would like to know which interpolation method are the browsers using to upscale my video. Is it in the HTML5 standard? Does it depend on the browser?

Comment: from Chromium notes it looks like linear interpolation, but seems to depend on browser and if it's using hardware or software video acceleration

Comment: No, its not part of the standard. each browser if fee to do whatever they wish

Comment: I'm also wondering about downscaling (as opposed to upscaling).